# AWS CloudFormation - using !Ref inside !Sub

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-service-catalog

I'm writing AWS CloudFormation template (using yaml) which creates AWS Service Catalog Product.
I'm getting the template for the product using parameter S3FilePath which has a value like the above path: https://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template.yml.
The URL to the file needs to be send in a JSON format as shown here (this example works):

```
Resources:
    Type: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct
    Properties: 
      Description: Example Product
      Distributor: xyz
      Name: ExampleProduct
      Owner: xyz
      ProvisioningArtifactParameters: 
        - Description: Example Product
          Info: { "LoadTemplateFromURL": "https://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template.yml" }
          Name: Version1
```

I tried to replace the URL using !Sub and !Ref as shown below:

```
Parameters:
  S3FilePath:
      Type: String
      Description: file name
Resources:
    Type: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct
    Properties: 
      Description: Example Product
      Distributor: xyz
      Name: ExampleProduct
      Owner: xyz
      ProvisioningArtifactParameters: 
        - Description: Example Product
          Info: !Sub
            - '{ "LoadTemplateFromURL": "${FILEPATH}" }'
            - {FILEPATH: !Ref S3FilePath}
          Name: Version1
```

But the CloudFormation stack fails with the error: "invalid input".
I guess I am building the JSON in a wrong way, I tried to use \ before each ' " ' but it didn't help either and I couldn't find an example which explain how to build this correctly. There is no problem with the S3FilePath parameter.

Can you please advice how to use the !Sub and !Ref correctly to build the JSON? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c25c28c59c11

Despite the documentation saying the Info parameter is JSON, the example shows just a name/value pair (Map): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-servicecatalog-cloudformationproduct-provisioningartifactproperties.html

Try formatting your string as

```
Info: !Sub
  - "LoadTemplateFromURL": "${FILEPATH}"
  - {FILEPATH: !Ref S3FilePath}
```

Comment: Hi, 
I have tried to do so but I still get the error.
This time I have enabled a trace and I got the following extended error: Property validation failure: [Value of property {/ProvisioningArtifactParameters/0/Info} does not match type {Map}]

Comment: I updated the example to match the example listed at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-servicecatalog-cloudformationproduct-provisioningartifactproperties.html

Comment: Hi, also tried the updated example, yet, getting the same error: 
[Value of property {/ProvisioningArtifactParameters/0/Info} does not match type {Map}].

received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: ["Invalid Input."]

Answer (score 1):

You can reference any Parameters or LogicalResourceId directly inside a `!Sub` like so:

```
  ProvisioningArtifactParameters: 
    - Description: Example Product
      Info: !Sub '{ "LoadTemplateFromURL": "${S3FilePath}" }'
      Name: Version1
```

This should work totally fine. The way you were doing substitutions is useful when you want to use conditions and/or mapping inside a `!Sub`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried. Yet, getting the same error: 
[Value of property {/ProvisioningArtifactParameters/0/Info} does not match type {Map}].

received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: ["Invalid Input."]

Comment: My bad, but do take my advice on the `!Sub`, it's easier to use that way. Let me see if I can still help, I already had errors like these in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be simply:

```
     ProvisioningArtifactParameters: 
        - Description: Example Product
          Info: 
            LoadTemplateFromURL: !Ref S3FilePath
          Name: Version1
```

This is at least what I have in my own `AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct` templates.

```
      ProvisioningArtifactParameters: 
        - DisableTemplateValidation: false
          Info: 
            LoadTemplateFromURL: !Ref S3FilePath
```

Comment: Hi, 
I have tried but still getting UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: ["Invalid Input."]

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik So the cause may be somewhere else. This is the form I use and it works. How does `S3FilePath` look like?

Comment: In the above scenario it had the value "https://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template.yml", I have tried with and without quote marks, can you please tell me how the value looked like in your code?

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik In my case it is full url, with `https://` at the beginning, e.g. `https://my-service-catalog-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/template.yaml`.

Comment: I have wrongly pasted it in the above comment, it had the value "https://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template.yml" so I am still not sure what is the issue..

Comment: @YuvalPodoksik I re-checked what I have in my templates. I also use `DisableTemplateValidation` flag as in the updated answer. Maybe the flag is required?